# This wcf service is running... what kind of binding is that ? which is default binding ? anybody explain ?

Tags: wcf, basichttpbinding

i did not added any kind of binding in web.config.But it is responding to the client request.There is no even a binding element in the web.config. Then why?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with WCF 4.0, the concept of default bindings (as well as default behaviors and default endpoints) was introduced.

Out of the box, with no entries in the config file, any requests coming over http will use `basicHttpBinding`, and the endpoint (for IIS-hosted services) will be based on the base address (for IIS, the location of the .svc file).  This is why your service works and the client can connect to it.

For more information, I suggest you take a look at [A Developer's Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation 4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx)